How to bind custom Image loader to Image UI element on Angular Nativescript
I have Nativescript Angular form like this:
 <ListView #list [items]="items" >
     <ng-template let-i="index" #template >
        <GridLayout orientation="horizontal"  >
          <Image [nsRouterLink]="['/item', items[i].key ]" />
 ...

How to create function what load Image Style and Src manually with my own logic.
As any developer with ASP experience I expected attribute something like ImageLoader = "myLoader (this)", but no.
How to bind custom Image loader to Image UI control?

answer is [src] attribute, something like this
  <Image [src]="myCustomLogic(items[i].key) | async"

